# Erratic auto dimming in new Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition

Tags: 18.04, dell

I just started using a new XPS 13 Developer Edition which came from the factory with Ubuntu 18.04. I did run the updates and that made my problem worse, if anything. The problem is an erratic auto dimming behavior. I'm not sure what the intended behavior is, but I am guessing that it will dim the screen when you're running on the battery or if the battery power percentage gets below a certain threshold, or maybe if you haven't moved the cursor after some time. However, mine is erratically dimming and undimming sometimes, in a loop. It's very noticeable and annoying.

As a workaround, in Settings -> Power -> Automatic Brightness, I can switch it to Off. That works around the issue for now. However, I would assume that Dell intends for this feature to work.

ANy recommendations on how I can resolve and get the intended behavior?